# How to fix sonar avoid large class rule?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am declaring the varieables in my app like this.But showing sonar issue as 
This type contains fields common prefixes: 2 fields prefixed with 'm_app'.
This type contains fields common prefixes: 2 fields prefixed with 'm_status'.

```
 private IRepository<ApplicationRoleRequest> m_appRoleRequestRepo;
        private IRepository<ApplicationRequestData> m_appRequestDataRepo;
        private IRepository<StatusReason> m_statusReasonRepo;
        private IRepository<Status> m_statusRepo;
```

Better way to declare the variables to support standard and how to avoid above error ?